# Using prefetch_related on category, subcategory and features

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to loop over my `FeatureCatergories`, `FeatureSubcategories` and `Features`. I'm able to loop over my feature categories just fine. Now I want to loop over my feature subcategories and finally features. I'm not sure what to call in my template for subcategories.. Should it be `{{featuresubcategory.title}}`? What about `features`?

**views.py**

```
def features_view(request):
    context = {
        "feature_categories": FeatureCategory.objects.prefetch_related('featuresubcategory_set').all(),
    }
    return render(request=request, template_name="main/features.html", context=context)
```

**template.html**

```
{% for category in feature_categories %}
    {{category.title}}
    {% for subcategory in featuresubcategory %}
        {{ subcategory.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

**models.py**

```
class FeatureCategory(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    featured_image = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to="features/")
    category_slug = AutoSlugField(null=True, default=None,
                         unique=True, populate_from='title')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Feature Categories"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class FeatureSubcategory(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.ForeignKey('FeatureCategory', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category_slug = AutoSlugField(null=True, default=None,
                         unique=True, populate_from='title')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Feature Subcategories"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Feature(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(FeatureSubcategory)
    description = models.TextField()
    featured_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_dir)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Features"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Can a subcategory also contain subcategories?  There is probably a better way of doing this.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica I'm open to ideas

Comment: my answer depends on whether or not your categories are *recursively nested*, which is what it looks like you are trying to accomplish.  "Can a subcategory also contain subcategories?"

Comment: In this case I only have the need for categories and subcategories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your template, you must change

`featuresubcategory` with `category.featuresubcategory_set.all()`
 also,

use `prefetch_related('featuresubcategory')` instead of `prefetch_related('featuresubcategory_set')`

```
{% for category in feature_categories %}
{{category.title}}
    {% for subcategory in category.featuresubcategory_set.all %}
        {{ subcategory.title }}

    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

- For features of subcategory, add related_name to your category field

`category = models.ManyToManyField(FeatureSubcategory,related_name='subcategory_features')`

and now, you can use it in your template, and don't forget to make migrate

```
 {% for category in feature_categories %}
    {{category.title}}
    {% for subcategory in category.featuresubcategory_set.all %}
        {{ subcategory.title }}
         {% for feature in subcategory.subcategory_features.all %}
              {{feature.title}}
        {% endfor %}


    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

You can see related objects reference [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/)

Comment: I'm getting `Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'category.featuresubcategory_set.all()'`

Comment: @GTA.sprx sorry, it's my fault, please remove brackets from `all()` keyword.

Comment: Works perfect! Any ideas on how to show the features that belong to each subcategory?

Comment: Hmmm for some reason the features aren't showing up

Comment: Did you make makemigrations and migrate?And have you any feature in your db for featuresubcategory?

Comment: Is it possible to do this with select_related?